# prove that it's a constant function

Tags: calculus

Let $~f~$ be a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that : 
$~~\forall x \in \mathbb{R}~~ $  , $~~f(x) = f(2x) $

and $f$ is continuous at $~0$ .

prove that $f$ is a constant function .

Comment: Accumulation point to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** For all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let define: $$x_n:=\frac{x}{2^n}.$$
For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f(x_n)=f(x)$ and $(x_n)_n$ converges to $0$.